# Fourier Transform in R^n

Tags: fourier-transform, gaussian-integral

This is the equation im trying to prove

$$P_y(\textbf{x})=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\int{e}^{i\textbf{k}\cdot\bf{x}}{e}^{-y|\textbf{k}|}\ d\textbf{k}=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{(n+1)}{2})}{\pi\frac{^{(n+1)}}{2}}\frac{y}{(|\textbf{x}|^2+y^2)^\frac{(n+1)}{2}}$$

And the help I have

$${e}^{-b}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{{e}^{-s}}{\sqrt{\pi s}}{e}^\frac{{-b^2}}{4s}ds,\qquad b\gt0.$$

I am supposed to use the help to substitute y|k| with b and swap the integrals, then use the Fourier Transformation of the Gaussian. k is an element of R^n in this context.

I have no idea how to properly use the Fourier Transformation of a Gaussian for an element of $R^n$. I would appreciate any help with that.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.

Comment: I am stuck at the start. I want to know how to do a Fourier transformation of a Gaussian works for:

e^(a|x|^2)

Comment: Start with $\mathcal F[k \mapsto e^{-k^2/2}](x) = e^{-x^2/2}/\sqrt {2 \pi}$ in one dimension. Then find the FT of $\boldsymbol k \mapsto e^{-k^2/2}$ in $\mathbb R^n$ by writing the FT as a product of one-dimensional integrals. Then use the scaling property of the FT to find the FT of $\boldsymbol k \mapsto e^{-y^2 k^2/(4 s)}$. The outer integral will become $\int_0^\infty s^{a - 1} e^{-b s} ds = b^{-a} \Gamma(a)$.

Comment: I solved it. Thank you very much.